# Rails: impact of lots of gems on performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, rubygems

What impact, if any, does having A LOT of gems have on the performance of your Rails app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the biggest impact is when your rails app starts up, as the gems are all loaded into memory. If you have lots of gems loaded, chances are you'll also have a lot of code loaded that your app doesn't use, so one way to cut down on the memory usage is to take advantage of copy-on-write support in the linux kernel. One way to do this is to use [ree and unicorn, as github did](http://github.com/blog/517-unicorn)

This is just an assumption though. You should always profile your app when dealing with timing and memory questions. It can make a really useful blog post.

Answer (score 1):

no impact on performance. It's just a problem of memory. You memory can be very big with so much gem and if you really use it.